# System.Linq.Dynamic using ?? c# operador

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I would like to use the ?? operator, and thus avoid large chains have to use the IIF operator.

Example:

```
customers.Select ("new (CompanyName as Name, Phone)");

customers.Select ("new (CompanyName as Name, iif (Phone = null, string.Empty, Phone) as Phone)");

customers.Select ("new (CompanyName as Name, (Phone ?? string.Empty) as Phone)");
```

Or maybe there's another way to do this.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you want to do. Can you post more code, such as the class and an attempt?

Comment: Is it unclear? He's basically asking, if it is possible to use `Phone ?? string.Empty` instead of `iif (Phone = null, string.Empty, Phone)`, in Dynamic Linq.

Answer (score 1):

See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library
and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx

Dynamic linq takes a string and converts it to the Linq equivalent.
You can even get source code form links and check the parse of string options.

**I just checked the library and think it would have very little  chance of doing what you want.**
the tokenId enum says a lot about what is possible
I just opened the Parser and saw this....

```
 private enum TokenId {
        Unknown,
        End,
        Identifier,
        StringLiteral,
        IntegerLiteral,
        RealLiteral,
        Exclamation,
        Percent,
        Amphersand,
        OpenParen,
        CloseParen,
        Asterisk,
        Plus,
        Comma,
        Minus,
        Dot,
        Slash,
        Colon,
        LessThan,
        Equal,
        GreaterThan,
        Question,
        OpenBracket,
        CloseBracket,
        Bar,
        ExclamationEqual,
        DoubleAmphersand,
        LessThanEqual,
        LessGreater,
        DoubleEqual,
        GreaterThanEqual,
        DoubleBar
    }
```

Comment: I'm currently using the library provided on the site: https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic. It has new elements that do not have the original Microsoft. But it lacks that functionality and would like to include.
Using Linq is very simple: Table.Select (s => new {Res s.Field1 ?? = ""});
Similarly it would be very efficient say Table.Select ("new (Field1 ?? \" \ " as Res)");

Someone wants constribuir?

Thank you.

Comment: I see no issue with adding null coalesce at that point, it would be evaluated before passing to Linq to entities.  The linq to entities library doesnt change. Only this string based fascade. So by all means, improve it to support other operators